# type is not subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>' in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a data that I pulled from json. I want to receive and process this data in the following format. When I try manually, I get the error with the actual service data while getting the output I want. My manual attempt:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final map = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
    {'MAH_ID': 10, 'MAH_AD': 'AŞAĞI', 'ILCE_ID': 1, 'ILCE_AD': 'SARI'},
    {'MAH_ID': 11, 'MAH_AD': 'YUKARI', 'ILCE_ID': 1, 'ILCE_AD': 'SARI'},
    {'MAH_ID': 12, 'MAH_AD': 'SAĞ', 'ILCE_ID': 1, 'ILCE_AD': 'SARI'},
    {'MAH_ID': 13, 'MAH_AD': 'SOL', 'ILCE_ID': 1, 'ILCE_AD': 'SARI'},
    {'MAH_ID': 14, 'MAH_AD': 'LOW', 'ILCE_ID': 2, 'ILCE_AD': 'KIRMIZI'},
    {'MAH_ID': 15, 'MAH_AD': 'MİD', 'ILCE_ID': 2, 'ILCE_AD': 'KIRMIZI'},
    {'MAH_ID': 16, 'MAH_AD': 'HİGH', 'ILCE_ID': 2, 'ILCE_AD': 'KIRMIZI'},
    {'MAH_ID': 17, 'MAH_AD': 'ULTRAHİGH', 'ILCE_ID': 2, 'ILCE_AD': 'KIRMIZI'}
  ];

  final mappedValues = <Map<String, List<dynamic>>>[];

  for (final element in map) {
    final ilceAd = element['ILCE_AD'];
    final mahAd = element['MAH_AD'];

    final contains =
        mappedValues.where((e) => e.keys.contains(ilceAd)).toList();

    if (contains.isNotEmpty) {
      if (contains.first.isNotEmpty) {
        if (contains.first.containsKey(ilceAd)) {
          contains.first[ilceAd]!.add(mahAd);
        }
      }
    } else {
      mappedValues.add({
        ilceAd as String: [mahAd]
      });
    }
  }

  print(mappedValues);
}
```

success output
`{SARI: [AŞAĞI, YUKARI, SAĞ, SOL]}, {KIRMIZI: [LOW, MİD, HİGH, ULTRAHİGH]}]`

my model class

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Mahalle> mahalleFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Mahalle>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Mahalle.fromJson(x)));

String mahalleToJson(List<Mahalle> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Mahalle {
  Mahalle({
    this.mahId,
    this.mahAdi,
    this.mahIdDbb,
    this.ilceId,
    this.ilceAdi,
    this.ilceIdDbb,
  });

  int? mahId;
  String? mahAdi;
  int? mahIdDbb;
  int? ilceId;
  String? ilceAdi;
  int? ilceIdDbb;

  factory Mahalle.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Mahalle(
        mahId: json["MAH_ID"],
        mahAdi: json["MAH_ADI"],
        mahIdDbb: json["MAH_ID_DBB"],
        ilceId: json["ILCE_ID"],
        ilceAdi: json["ILCE_ADI"],
        ilceIdDbb: json["ILCE_ID_DBB"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "MAH_ID": mahId,
        "MAH_ADI": mahAdi,
        "MAH_ID_DBB": mahIdDbb,
        "ILCE_ID": ilceId,
        "ILCE_ADI": ilceAdi,
        "ILCE_ID_DBB": ilceIdDbb,
      };
}
```

method where i pull json data

```
Future getApiData() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result =
            mahalleFromJson(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

        final mappedValues = <Map<String, List<dynamic>>>[];

        for (final element in result) {
          final ilceAd = element['ilceAdi'];
          final mahAd = element["mahAdi"];

          final contains = mappedValues
              .where((element) => element.keys.contains(ilceAd))
              .toList();

          if (contains.isNotEmpty) {
            if (contains.first.isNotEmpty) {
              if (contains.first.containsKey(ilceAd)) {
                contains.first[ilceAd]!.add(mahAd);
              }
            }
          } else {
            mappedValues.add({
              ilceAd as String: [mahAd]
            });
          }
        }
        print(mappedValues);
}
```

the error i got:
type 'Mahalle' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element` in your `for loop` is an `Mahalle` Item, so if you want to access `ilceAd` or `mahAd` you should do this:

```
var result = mahalleFromJson(response.body); //<--- change this

final mappedValues = <Map<String, List<dynamic>>>[];

for (final element in result) {
          final ilceAd = element.ilceAdi; //<--- change this
          final mahAd = element.mahAdi; //<--- change this

          final contains = mappedValues
              .where((element) => element.keys.contains(ilceAd))
              .toList();

          if (contains.isNotEmpty) {
            if (contains.first.isNotEmpty) {
              if (contains.first.containsKey(ilceAd)) {
                contains.first[ilceAd]!.add(mahAd);
              }
            }
          } else {
            mappedValues.add({
              ilceAd as String: [mahAd]
            });
          }
        }
```

Comment: I can't get such access. Because the result is List<Map> while the element is just Map

Comment: I finally got it done mate. There was no need for the cast process above, it was solved by the method you said when you deleted it. Thank you so much.

Comment: glad to hear that. appreciate it if you up vote me.